# Where did I go wrong evaluating this integral?

Tags: integration

I wanted to see if complex analysis could help me evaluate the following integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^{−x} dx $$
It definitely converges due to the exponentially decaying function.

I began by substituting $\cos(x)$ with $\frac{e^{ix}+ e^{−ix}}{2}$:
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}+ e^{−ix}}{2} e^{−x} dx $$
Factor the $\frac{1}{2}$:
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{ix}+ e^{−ix}) e^{−x} dx $$
Distribute $e^{-x}$:
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ix}e^{-x} + e^{-ix}e^{-x} dx $$
Use the exponents rule:
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ix-x} + e^{-ix-x} dx $$
Factor:
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x(i-1)} + e^{-x(i+1)} dx$$
Using a simple u-substitution we evaluate the integral to be:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\frac{e^{ix-x}}{i-1} + \frac{e^{-ix-x}}{i+1}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Factor out $e^{-x}$:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{e^{ix}}{i-1} + \frac{e^{-ix}}{i+1}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Combine fractions:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{(i+1)e^{ix}+(i-1)e^{-ix}}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Expand: 
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{ie^{ix}+e^{ix}+ie^{-ix}-e^{-ix}}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Combine terms with an $i$ coefficient:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{(ie^{ix}+ie^{-ix})+(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Factor out an $i$:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{i(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Split the fraction:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{i(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{-2}+\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Factor the negative:
$$= -\frac{1}{2}\left [\left (i\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}+\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
The exponential definition of the cosine function is:
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
Multiply by $i$:
$$i\cos(x)=i\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

The exponential definition of the sine function is:
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Multiply by $i$:
$$i\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$$
We can substitute these back into our problem and get:
$$= -\frac{1}{2}\left [\left ( i\cos(x)+i\sin(x)  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Factor put the $i$:
$$= -\frac{i}{2}\left [\left ( \cos(x)+\sin(x)  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$$
Let:
$$A=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\cos(x)+\sin(x))$$
Since $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$ for $-\infty \le x \le \infty$ and $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$ for $-\infty \le x \le \infty$:
$$-2 \leq \cos(x)+\sin(x) \leq 2$$
This implies:
$$-2 \leq A \leq 2$$
As $x$ goes to infinity $e^{-x}$ goes to $0$
Evaluate bounds of integration:
$$= -\frac{i}{2}\left [A \cdot e^{-\infty} -(\cos(0)+\sin(0))\cdot e^0\right ]$$
$$= -\frac{i}{2}\left [A \cdot 0 -(1 + 0)\cdot 1\right ]$$
$$= -\frac{i}{2}\left [0 - 1\right ]$$
$$= -\frac{i}{2}(- 1)$$
$$= -\frac{i}{2}$$
So:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^{−x} dx = \frac{i}{2}$$
It's obvious that I went wrong somewhere, I just cant figure out where!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid integration by parts? This looks like an ideal candidate for IbP.

Comment: 'Using a simple u-substitution we evaluate the integral to be' - there should be a minus sign there. Also, at this step you can just sub in the limits. For infinity both of them will be zero.

Comment: "use a simple u-substitution ..." forgot minus sign

Comment: it still doesn't change that the final result is imaginary

Comment: actually, yea it does

Comment: @mathworker21 oooops, I actually got 1/2 when i fixed the sign error

Comment: @Jakobian, I fixed the sign error got 1/2

Comment: At $I=\frac12\left[\frac{e^{x(i-1)}}{i-1}-\frac{e^{-x(i+1)}}{i+1}\right]_0^\infty$, why not just plug in your bounds? Doing so gives the correct answer and in much less steps...

Comment: @Clayton I couldnt use it because $\cos(x)$ can be differentiated infinatley many times and never reaches a constant  $e^-x$ also does this, so IbP wont work.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt wanted to remove the imaginary part so I expanded it so it could be written as a combination of sin and cos

Comment: Why though? That's just more unnecessary work...

Comment: You are kidding, right? Integration by parts works wonders here.

Comment: Yea it does work, didn't attempt it. I didn't think about solving for $\int e^x cos(x) dx$ and then dividing the expression by two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Why not integrating instead

$$
\mathcal{Re}\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{ix}e^{-x} dx\right)
$$

Easily we find

$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{ix}e^{-x} dx = \left.\frac{1}{i-1}e^{(i-1)x}\right]_0^{\infty} = \frac{1}{1-i} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac i2
$$

Comment: That's really elegant, I cant believe I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2):

You look fine up to here

$\frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{-2}+\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{-2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$

At this point, I would say:

$\frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{2i^2} - \frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{2}\left [\left (\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{2i} - \frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2}  \right ) e^{-x}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}$

Move back to trig functions.
It looks like you added an extra $i$ factor at this step.

$\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{2i} = \sin x, \frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2} = \cos x\\
\frac{1}{2}[(\sin x - \cos x ) e^{-x}]_{0}^{\infty}\\
$

and evaluate.

$-\frac{1}{2}[(\sin 0 - \cos 0 ) = \frac {1}{2}$

Alternatively, at a much earlier step

$\frac{1}{2}\left [\frac{e^{(ix-x}}{-1+i} + \frac{e^{-ix-x}}{-1-i}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{2}\left [\frac{e^{-x}(\cos x + i\sin x)}{-1+i} + \frac{e^{-x}(\cos x -i\sin x)}{-1-i}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\left [\frac{(-1-i)(\cos x + i\sin x) + (-1+i)(\cos x -i\sin x)}{(-1+i)(-1-i)}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\left [\frac{-\cos x -i\sin x - i\cos x + \sin x -\cos x + i\sin x + i\cos x + \sin x}{2}\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\left [-\cos x + \sin x\right ]_{0}^{\infty}\\
$